# Evaluate a expression split in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

I have a list with this format {integer, sign, integer, sign, integer}, sign being one of these: **Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide**. For example, let's say:

```
list = {1, Plus, 2, Times, 3};
```

I'm searching for something that would return the value of that expression, taking into account the precedence of each.

At first I tried to do something like:

```
list[[1]]~list[[2]]~list[[3]]~list[[4]]~list[[5]]
```

But the answer to this list using this method would be $(1 + 2) \times 3 = 3 \times 3 = 9$, where it should have been $1 + 2 \times 3 = 1 + 6 = 7$

Comment: `ToExpression[StringTake[StringReplace[ToString[{1, Plus, 2, Times, 3}/. {Plus -> "+", Times -> "*", Divide -> "/", Minus -> "-"}], "," -> ""], {2, -2}]]`

Comment: @Coolwater that's quite nice. Why don't you write it up as an answer instead?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe… I just can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution may be simple and rather "robust":

```
ToExpression[
  StringJoin[ToString /@ list /. {"Plus" -> "+", "Times" -> "*"}]
]
```

You may try it on:

```
list = {1, Plus, 2, Times, 3, Plus, "PlusPlus"}
```

where it correctly returns:

```
PlusPlus+7
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm *totally* cheating here, but you can use `SemanticInterpretation` in v10 to get you there.

```
SemanticInterpretation[StringRiffle[{1, Plus, 2, Times, 3}, " "]]
```

> `7`

:)

Comment: This deserves sooo many upvotes...

Comment: I have v10 but i didn't know this cool

Comment: For some reason, in my v10 I don't have `StringRiffle`. Someone knows why?

Comment: @Garmekain StringRiffle was a 10.1 introduction. Try StringJoin@Riffle instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
list //. ({x___, PatternSequence[a_, u : #, b_], y___} :> 
         {x, u[a, b], y} & /@ {(Times | Divide), (Plus | Subtract)})

(*  {7} *)

f[list_] := list //. ({x___, PatternSequence[a_, u : #, b_], y___} :> 
                      {x, u[a, b], y} & /@ {(Times | Divide), (Plus | Subtract)})

{#, f@#} & /@ (Riffle[{a, b, c}, #] & /@ Tuples[{Times, Divide, Plus, Subtract}, 2]) // 
                                                                                  Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]